# Wildfly 12 - Communication between 2 WARs within EAR - JSF Beans (@ManagedBeans / @Named)

Tags: jsf-2.2, ear, managed-bean, wildfly-12

Is there a way to perform a communication between WARs within an EAR deployment archive in such a way that it would be possible not just to make usage of JSF Managed Beans (annotated as `@ManagedBean` or `@Named`) as well as Facelets resources from one WAR to another and vice-versa?

The JEE container used is the Wildfly 12.

Our project's structure is similar to the following one:

> - EAR
>
>   - A.war
>   - B.war
>   - ejb.jar

I've read some articles mentioning the ***shared session*** configuration inside **jboss-all.xml** file descriptor.

Some other articles suggests the ***ear-subdeployments-isolated*** usage set to `false` in the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** file descriptor.

Are there other ways to achieve that rather than the suggestions above? More over, is that possible to achieve such communication?

Thanks.

Comment: @Named annotated classes are CDI managed ones, not JSF managed ones

Comment: @ManagedBean is being deprecated... It has being advised to replace it with CDI \@Named - https://javaserverfaces.github.io/docs/2.3/managed-bean-javadocs/deprecated-list.html.

Comment: yes, but I just stated  they are differently managed. Not to not use them

Comment: Sure, no problem.